# Put a variable as text on a button, when i click the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

So I have a color randomizer for the button background color. I am trying to put the color that returns from the variable `color` and put it as text on the button. I also want this to happen on click.

Example:
I click on the button, a random color sets on the button background color. That color is `#ff0000`. I want the button to say something like:

> "The background color of this button is x"

Where `x` is the exact color as the background, but in text.

Here is my js:

```
    function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color='#';
    for (var i = 0; i<6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;


}

function setRandomColor(){
    $("#buttonB").css("background-color", getRandomColor())

}
```

and here is what i have in html:

```
<div>
        <button id="buttonB" class="button" onclick="setRandomColor();">


        </button>
    </div>
```

I also have the jquery library to it.

Answer (score 2):

take the result of getRandomColor(), and save it to a variable, and apply to both locations: the text, and the css.

This would change just the setRandomColor() function.

JS:

```
function setRandomColor(){
    var color = getRandomColor()
    $("#buttonB").css("background-color", color)
    $("#buttonB").html("Button color: "+color)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function setRandomColor(){
    var color = getRandomColor();
    $("#buttonB").css("background-color", color).html("The background color of this button is " + color);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to take the color returned from your `getRandomColor` function and set it to the background and text of your button.

Like this:

```js
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color='#';
    for (var i = 0; i<6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    
    return color;


}

function setRandomColor(){
    var color = getRandomColor();
    $("#buttonB").css("background-color", color );
    $("#buttonB").text("My color is " + color );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>  
      <button id="buttonB" class="button" onclick="setRandomColor();">
        Click me!
      </button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1-Just change remove `onclick` attribute from `<button>` tag

```
<button id="buttonB" class="button">
     click to change
</button>
```

2- Add click event handler

```
$("#buttonB").on('click',function(){
    var new_color = getRandomColor();
    $(this).css("background-color", new_color);
    $(this).text('bg color: '+new_color);
});
```

Comment: this would not work, since getRandomColor() would generate new color code each time it is called, hence causing your background-color and text to have outmatching values.

Comment: Let me correct it @CanerAkdeniz,   you deserve a cookie :)